# process run by pexpect.run() method terminates abruptly

Tags: python, jenkins, pexpect

When i run below code i see the process terminates even before completion.
I validated command by running it manually command just works file.
cmssso-util produces output which are about 1200 lines.Can this be a buffer issue.
I validated script by assigning 'ls -ltr' to variable command works fine.
Referred Documentation from below link:
https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/pexpect/run.html

- I tried prefixing command by 'bash -c' which did not fix this issue.
- I tried to find out how pexpect determines to terminate a process , still could not get any clear documentation.
  Please help me.

```
import pexpect
command = "cmsso-util domain-repoint -m execute  --src-emb-admin " + 'sourceVcAdmin' + " --replication-partner-fqdn " + 'destVc' + " --replication-partner-admin " + 'destVcAdmin' + " --dest-domain-name " +    'destDomain'

print("Running command  : " + command) 

(command_output, exitstatus) =   pexpect.run(command ,withexitstatus=1, events={'Enter Source embedded vCenter Server Admin Password :' : '\r\n','Enter Replication partner Platform Services Controller Admin Password :' : '\r\n','All Repoint configuration settings are correct; proceed?(.*)' :  'Y\r\n'})

print("----Command output------------")
print(command_output)
print("-----------------------------")

assert exitstatus is 0 , "Execution Failed"
print("Successfully Completed Embedded Cross Domain Re-pointing ")
```

Comment: Was there any output from the command?  Did that output indicate any error, or was it just unexpectedly truncated?

Comment: @jasonharper : Log did not show any error, process terminated unexpectedly.Same command when it was run manually process completed without any issue. last few lines of logsare here` :/usr/lib/vmware-sca/lib/lookup-client.jar:/usr/lib/vmware-sca/lib/*:/usr/lib/vmware-sca/lib\', \'-Dlog4j.configuration=tool-log4j.properties\', \'com.vmware.vim.lookup.client.tool.LsTool\', \'get\', \'--url\', \'https://vcsa.st.local:443/lookupservice/sdk\', \'--id\', \'f09ee5e1-0c3a-4808-9eee-8bc8bb0f3bd1\', \'--as-spec\']\r\n'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could resolve this issue by using the following code:

```
    import pexpect
try :
        command = "cmsso-util domain-repoint -m execute  --src-emb-admin " + 'sourceVcAdmin' + " --replication-partner-fqdn " + 'destVc' + " --replication-partner-admin " + 'destVcAdmin' + " --dest-domain-name " +    'destDomain'
        print("Running command  : " + command) 
        child = pexpect.spawn(command, timeout=3000,maxread=12000)
        child.expect (['Enter Source embedded vCenter Server Admin Password :'],timeout=40000)
        child.sendline(<password>)
        child.expect (['Enter Replication partner Platform Services Controller Admin Password :'],timeout=40000)
        child.sendline(<password>)
        child.expect (['All Repoint configuration settings are correct; proceed?(.*)'],timeout=40000)
        child.sendline('Y')
        child.expect(pexpect.EOF)
        print(child.before)   
        assert(child.status == 0 , "Operation Failed!", "Successfully Completed Embedded Cross Domain Re-pointing")
except:
    print("Exception was thrown")
    print("debug information:")
    print(str(child))
    child.close()
    exit(1)
```

This is done by increasing default child = pexpect.spawn(command, timeout=600,maxread=8000)value and **maxread** parameters